# how to import a module in environment that won't let it be a hazard to my computer? (python)

Tags: python, import, module, environment, virus

python 2.7

windows 7

I wan't to download a bunch of modules and run them. the programmer of these modules could make them contain a virus. to prevent this I would like to run these modules in an environment that won't let it import any modules unless I specify that it can import that certain module (a module I would let it import would be the math module, or other modules in the package. a module that I would restrict would be the os module.)

it this possible in any shape or form, even if it doesn't match all of the specifications I gave, or would I have to go through the code myself and make sure its fine.

Answer (score 1):

It's very hard to do correctly with CPython. PyPy has much better [sandboxing capabilities](http://pypy.org/features.html#sandboxing).

Answer (score 1):

One option may be to do virtualization of different environments, either at a lower level, like with VirtualBox (https://www.virtualbox.org/), or at a higher level, like with virtualenv (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv).